# Can't Scroll and highlight code in Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ace-editor

With the help of this community I was able to make my ace editor full height, so as the users typed or modified it the editor would grow with the code. I recently realized this prevents the user from trying to highlight the code. When you start to highlight the code and begin dragging down when you reach the bottom of the window it stop, it doesn't scroll the window down like you would expect.

Here is the code I am using to make the editor full height. A link to a JSFiddle is below

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor-html");

setEditorOptions(editor, 'html');

setTimeout(function() {
    heightUpdateFunction();
}, 100);    

function setEditorOptions(editor, type) {
    editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/clouds");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/"+type);
    editor.getSession().on('change', heightUpdateFunction);
}
function heightUpdateFunction() {
    var newHeight = (editor.getSession().getScreenLength() + 1) * editor.renderer.lineHeight + editor.renderer.scrollBar.getWidth();
    $('#editor-html').css('height', newHeight.toString() + "px");
    editor.resize();

    if (newHeight <= 1) {   
        setTimeout(function() {
            heightUpdateFunction();
        }, 100);    
    }
}
```

I have uploaded an example to try this out of [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/PCwud/9/).

Is there any way to fix the scrolling when a user tries to hightlight the text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `maxLines` and `autoScrollEditorIntoView` options. like this:

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor-html");
editor.setOptions({
    maxLines: 1000,
    autoScrollEditorIntoView: true,
    theme: "ace/theme/clouds",
    showPrintMargin: false,
    mode: "ace/mode/html"
})
```

see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/demo/autoresize.html#L39.

Note that `heightUpdateFunction` was suggested when `maxLines` option wasn't available yet and it doesn't work well. You should use `maxLines` instead of it.

Comment: Thank you so very much! I didn't even see the `autoScrollEditorIntoView` option. This solved my problem. Just to anyone using this answer, please keep in mind that `maxLines` adds a vertical scrollbar. Do not include `maxLines` if you want to avoid the scrollbar.

Comment: why do you think maxlines inludes vertical scrollbar? i don't see any scrollbars in http://ace.c9.io/demo/autoresize.html

Answer (score 0):

If can also happen if you set `scrollSpeed` to zero.

```
editor.setScrollSpeed(0); // no scrolling

editor.setScrollSpeed(.5); // scrolling
```

I had used an `integer` to store the `scrollSpeed` value and when I was passing it `.5` it was converted to 0 since `integers` can only be whole numbers and this disabled scrolling. I switched to using `Number` or `float` that allows decimals and scroll started working again.